# MessageConsumer is not consuming messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jboss7.x, message-queue

My application is running on Jboss 7.1.1. I have a scheduler that runs every one minute and needs to check if there are messages in the DLQ and do some updates in the DB.

I wrote a message consumer that listens to a predefined custom DLQ. The problem is that i can see that there are messages in the custom DLQ but `consumer.receiveNoWait()` always return null.

Here is the code for creating the consumer:

```
/*this is running fine and creating the consumer*/
public DestinationHandlerImpl(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    Destination destination, boolean useTransaction, int delMode,
    boolean isProducer) throws JMSException {
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
}
```

Here is the code that consumes the message (runs every one minute):

```
/*this always return null, event when there are messages in the queue*/
public <T extends BaseEvent> T recieveMessage()
        throws JMSException {

    Message message = consumer.receiveNoWait(); // ----> always return null!!!

    if (message != null && !(message instanceof ObjectMessage)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "message object has to be of type ObjectMessage");
    }

    // Extract the object from the message
    return message == null ? null : (T) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();

}
```

I've used debug mode and i can see the consumer destination property is set to the right queue, so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it, i just needed to add `connection.start()` before starting to consume.

```
public <T extends BaseEvent> T recieveMessage()
    throws JMSException {

    connection.start(); // --->**added this line**
    Message message = consumer.receiveNoWait(); 

    if (message != null && !(message instanceof ObjectMessage)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "message object has to be of type ObjectMessage");
    }

    // Extract the object from the message
    return message == null ? null : (T) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
}
```

Comment: I expect that you don't want to keep calling `start()` each minute, but rather you should call that once when you first open the connection.

Comment: I make sure to close the connection each time the scheduler starts.

Comment: May I ask why? Are you concerned with the resource consumption of the open connection?

Comment: This is actually part of a very large system that was designed long time ago, i just added a new adapter that uses the system mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, made the same mistake. Odd because I used the same connection to send and receive via two queues, sending worked without calling connection.Start()

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem even with `connection.start()`! The working solution for me:

Use [`receive(long timeout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive%28long%29) instead of [`receiveNoWait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receiveNoWait%28%29);

Obs.: 1000 milliseconds as the timeout worked fine in a simple test case, but just to be sure at production, I'm configuring it with 10000 milliseconds. In my case, while iterating the messages, I stop when I receive `null` (no more messages) and in that last call, the receive(10000) waits the full 10 seconds (obviously). I had to use an asynchronous approach to mitigate that performance issue.

---

**Edit:** Also, depending on the implementation (jbm), it may have some messages prefetched (preselected to be consumed) and that makes the messages unavailable since they are at *delivering* status.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem. I really don't like calling receive with timeout though, because that is (by definition) a race condition. You ever learn any more about this?

Comment: @fool4jesus Sorry, I couldn't find anything further in my research over that case. Actually, the above really worked fine for me.